# Install another language in deepspeech with node js

Tags: node.js, mozilla-deepspeech

I am trying to use mozilla-deepspeech in my project to generate text to voice. How do i use it for another language than English? I want to convert to Indonesia language.

Note: I am using NodeJS as a base project on windows.

Thank you for your solution

Answer (score 0):

1. You need an Indonesian model that is downloadable. [Check this list](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/error-when-trying-to-decode-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-std-length-error/67967).
2. Simply load another model and scorer via the API and provide the audio.